# How can I create a 2nd thread, have progressdialog and pause the main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, parsing, progressdialog

Sorry, I am new to Android programming.  I have an xml parser that I don't want running in the UI thread.  I want to display a progressdialog while the parser is running in its own thread but I don't want the main thread to start the next Activity until the parser is finished.  I have code but the progressdialog doesn't display for the full duration.  In place of the while loop, i've tried parserThread.join() with the same results.  Also, I want to avoid timing out the UI thread.  Any help is appreciated.

My method that invokes the thread, followed by the class that implements Runnable:

```
private void parseGasStationData() {
        gasStations = null;
        StationParser sp = new StationParser(activity);
        Thread parserThread = new Thread(sp);
        parserThread.start();
        while (parserThread.isAlive()) {
            // do nothing
        }
        gasStations = sp.getList();
        Log.v("Parser-Status", "xml parsed successfully: "
                + (gasStations != null));
    }

public class StationParser implements Runnable {
    private Activity activity;
    private final ProgressDialog pd;

    public StationParser(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Parsing data...", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            runParser();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.e("Parser-Error", "XmlPullParserException", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Parser-Error", "IOException", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Parser-Error", "ParseException", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pd.dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In android we use the `AsyncTask` class to make background operations an show the results. See the main document page [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) the first example seems pretty useful for you, just change the `doInBackground` method for your parser.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
while (parserThread.isAlive()) {
    // do nothing
}
```

needs to go. As long as you have that, you might as well not be using a separate thread at all. (In fact, it's worse, because it's a "[busy wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)" that hogs the CPU.)

The right way to do this is with a call-back. When the parsing thread is done, it can call `post(Runnable)` to run a process on the UI thread that will make the progress dialog go away. You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to help with this. See the guide topic [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) for more information.

Comment: AsyncTask appears to have a very obfuscated API.  I'm trying it out and so far, I can't turn the Progressdialog off and I have no idea how to return my arraylist to the calling class.

Comment: AsyncTask is designed to deliver the results in its `onPostExecute` method. That's where you would turn off the progress dialog and set the arraylist. You should not think of this as if it were calling a method and returning a result. You start a separate thread that goes off and does its thing on its own schedule and reports back to your main thread when the work is done. The main thread needs to be designed with this decoupling in mind. The main thread should start up the AsyncTask/worker thread and then return control to the OS (to avoid an "application not responding" error).

Comment: I don't have much experience with threads.  Do I need to have a getter method that returns my arrayList when using AsyncTask?  Eventually, the UI thread will start another Activity.  I don't want the parser running during the next Activity.  How does this ensure that the parser finishes before the next Activity is started?

Comment: In the `onPostExecute` method of the AsyncTask, you can launch the second activity, or you can call a method of your main activity, passing the result to it. `onPostExecute` will only be called after the `doInBackground` method finishes, and it runs on the UI thread. If you make the AsyncTask an inner class of the activity, you have full access to the activity's fields and methods from within `onPostExecute`.

Comment: never mind.  I got it working.  I see it has some intelligence.  It has a get() method and knows exactly what I want returned.

Comment: Thanks Ted.  I think that last post from you was also a big help.  Your idea of starting the activity from the onPostExecute may work out fine.

Comment: @jpdunn - Just be sure not to call `get` on the UI thread. That will risk an Application Not Responding sentence for the app.